# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - April 2018

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the seventh edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for April 2018

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Close Votes Reviewed Award
6. Most First Posts Reviewed Award
7. Most Late Answers Reviewed Award
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award
9. Most Reopen Reviews Award
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                    SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                  420
2   Allan                      330
3   Nimesh Neema               270
4   Swisher Sweet              130
5   grgarside                  120
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 850.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,714 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2018-04-01).

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   Nimesh Neema             195
2   Monomeeth                 57
3   bmike                     51
4   Allan                     43
5   grgarside                 40
```

A big thank you to all 27 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,453
2   Monomeeth                 917
3   Nimesh Neema              435
4   Citizen                   210
5   bro                       160
```

A big thank you to all 67 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1. Note: Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST CLOSE VOTES REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                 53
2   Allan                     51
3   patrix                    41
4   dwightk                   39
5   Mark                      35
```

A big thank you to all 22 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST FIRST POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth                332
2   Nimesh Neema             152
3   Scot                     110
4   Allan                    108
5   patrix                   107
```

A big thank you to all 38 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LATE ANSWERS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     79
2   Glorfindel                61
3   Scot                      44
4   Nimesh Neema              38
5   fsb                       29
```

A big thank you to all 31 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST LOW-QUALITY POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     53
2   Scot                      23
3   Nimesh Neema, Monomeeth   21
4   IconDaemon                15
5   fd0                       12
```

A big thank you to all 24 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST REOPEN POSTS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                    16
2   dwightk                   8
3   patrix, Monomeeth         7
4   Glorfindel, Mark          6  
5   grgarside, Tetsujin       5
```

A big thank you to all 16 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST SUGGESTED EDITS REVIEWED AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                 REVIEWS
---------------------------------------
1   Monomeeth               115
2   Allan                    77
3   Nimesh Neema             61
4   Glorfindel               40
5   Scot                     38
```

A big thank you to all 58 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Installation of macOS High Sierra Update 10.13.4 failed; how do I recover without losing data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321244/installation-of-macos-high-sierra-update-10-13-4-failed-how-do-i-recover-withou)

   - Posted by: Swisher Sweet
   - Votes: **37**
2. [I need to disable my main keyboard as one letter is not working and it's out of warranty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322176/i-need-to-disable-my-main-keyboard-as-one-letter-is-not-working-and-its-out-of)

   - Posted by: Michal Stefanow
   - Votes: **16**
3. [Is there a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable hidden files in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322808/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-enable-disable-hidden-files-in-finder)

   - Posted by: J. Doe
   - Votes: **15**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1st. [I need to disable my main keyboard as one letter is not working and it's out of warranty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322176/i-need-to-disable-my-main-keyboard-as-one-letter-is-not-working-and-its-out-of/322204#322204)

- Answered by: BaconDuctTape
- Votes: **31**

Equal 2nd. [I need to disable my main keyboard as one letter is not working and it's out of warranty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322176/i-need-to-disable-my-main-keyboard-as-one-letter-is-not-working-and-its-out-of/322178#322178)

- Answered by: Steve Chambers
- Votes: **24**

Equal 2nd. [Is there a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable hidden files in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322808/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-enable-disable-hidden-files-in-finder/322809#322809)

- Answered by: Monomeeth
- Votes: **24**

3rd. [Installation of macOS High Sierra Update 10.13.4 failed; how do I recover without losing data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321244/installation-of-macos-high-sierra-update-10-13-4-failed-how-do-i-recover-withou/321287#321287)

- Answered by: Swisher Sweet
- Votes: **21**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [Installation of macOS High Sierra Update 10.13.4 failed; how do I recover without losing data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321244/installation-of-macos-high-sierra-update-10-13-4-failed-how-do-i-recover-withou)

   - Posted by: Swisher Sweet
   - Views: **16,827**
2. [Fortnite for iOS reports insufficient space on my iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321441/fortnite-for-ios-reports-insufficient-space-on-my-iphone)

   - Posted by: c. Bobert
   - Views: **6,306**
3. [System won't boot after attempting 10.13.4 update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321146/system-wont-boot-after-attempting-10-13-4-update?s=1%7C124.3691)

   - Posted by: Sokel
   - Views: **5,571**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [Nimesh Neema](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Close Votes Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**6.    Most First Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**7.    Most Late Answers Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Low-Quality Posts Reviewed Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Reopen Reviews Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award**

- [Monomeeth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168832/monomeeth)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [Swisher Sweet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/18285/swisher-sweet)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [BaconDuctTape](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/285001/baconducttape)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [Swisher Sweet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/18285/swisher-sweet)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In April our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned 658 flags with an average handling time of 14 minutes. In summary, we also:

- deleted 371 comments
- deleted 260 posts
- closed 201 posts
- edited 231 posts
- created 139 posts
- created 454 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)